# Troubles with files in C

Tags: c, file

I am trying to write functions to help me with saving and loading files... but when I try to save my array from the file it is not matching the original one that I loaded in to the file. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "intarr.h"

/* LAB 6 TASK 1 */

/*
  Save the entire array ia into a file called 'filename' in a binary
  file format that can be loaded by intarr_load_binary(). Returns
  zero on success, or a non-zero error code on failure. Arrays of
  length 0 should produce an output file containing an empty array.
*/

int intarr_save_binary( intarr_t* ia, const char* filename )
{
  FILE* f = fopen( "filename", "wb" );

  if( f == NULL )
  {
    return 1;
  }

  if( fwrite( &ia->len, sizeof( int ), 1, f ) != 1 )
  {
    return 1;
  }

  if( fwrite( &ia->data, sizeof( int ), ia->len, f ) != ia->len )
  {
    return 1;
  }

  fclose( f );

  return 0;
}

/*
  Load a new array from the file called 'filename', that was
  previously saved using intarr_save_binary(). Returns a pointer to a
  newly-allocated intarr_t on success, or NULL on failure.
*/

intarr_t* intarr_load_binary( const char* filename )
{
  if( filename == NULL )
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  FILE* f = fopen( "filename", "rb" );

  if( f == NULL )
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  int len;

  if( fread( &len, sizeof( int ), 1, f ) != 1 )
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  intarr_t* new_ia = intarr_create( len );

  fread( new_ia->data, sizeof( int ), len, f );

  fclose( f );

  return new_ia;
}
```

Also just to be clear intarr_t ia is just a struct with ia->data (array) and ia->len (len of array)

Comment: What data are you saving? What is wrong with the data that is loaded?

Comment: Q: Have you tried looking at the output file in a hex editor, or the input struct with a debugger?  Q: Is there any chance the readers/writers might have different byte endianness?

Comment: We can't tell what type `ia->data` is. We can't tell what `intarr_create` does. This makes it hard to give a good answer.

Comment: Yes, it's not a very clear question, but you can infer a pretty good guess at the type by looking at the `fread` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line here, you are writing the contents of the pointer, not the data it points to.   If the length is sufficient, you'll potentially write other random data that follows it, subject to *undefined behavior*:

```
fwrite( &ia->data, sizeof( int ), ia->len, f )
```

The problem is that you added one extra level of redirection by taking the address of `ia->data`.  It seems like you just had a copy-paste error or something.  Remove the `&`:

```
fwrite( ia->data, sizeof( int ), ia->len, f )
```